# adding third party Javascript library without installing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a javascript library [specifically **[KindEditor](http://kindeditor.org/download)**] in my react app, but i am not able to incorporate.

> I can't install this library through npm install because **i want to
>   extend or do some customizations in this library.**

Can someone help me adding a javascript library  in react js app?

Answer (score 1):

You can always do it the old way, like with jQuery, in the index.html before your bundle.js, use the script tag with 'src' attribute and point it to the .js file that you want to use. Now it should be available globally and you can use it in anywhere, of course, if there is no namespace clashing.

Comment: can you provide some example in which i can use the javascript library in my custom component?

Comment: How are you developing react app? with create-react-app cli or with webpack configs?

Comment: with create-react-app cli, without webpack. 
i am currently trying to integrate froala editor[link](https://github.com/froala/react-froala-wysiwyg), but getting following error.

ReferenceError: '$' is undefined

exception string:
> 1 | !function(e,t){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=t(require("react")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["react"],t):"object"==typeof exports?exports.index=t(require("react")):e.index=t(e.React)}(this,function(e){return function(e){function t(i){if(n[i])return n[i].exports;var o=n[i]=

Comment: i want to know how can i import jquery config as it is defined in [Farola](https://github.com/froala/react-froala-wysiwyg) documentation.